# How to troubleshoot a CMake build non-reproducible SegFault

Tags: c++, cmake, bamboo

I have a C++ project that uses CMake to build and we also have Atlassian Bamboo as CI build server. My tests are defined using C++ GoogleTest. I have a test case `suite_simple_budgeting` that when executed as standalone executable works fine and all tests pass but when I run it as part of the CI build i.e. `make test` or `ctest -T Test` it fails with `SegFault`. To make things more complicated, this only happens with the Bamboo CI build, as my user I don't get the SegFault either way. If I run it under valgrind I see no errors either.

Is there a flag or way to reveal what's going on while running the tests via `ctest -T Test` e.g. I would like to see the exception output, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you have a look at the testing output cmake generates. It's located in the `build dir/Testing/...`, there should at least be the output the program prints to `std::out` and `std::err`

Comment: @ruslo add this as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-VV` argument to see all the ctest output:

```
-VV,--extra-verbose

    Enable more verbose output from tests.

    Test output is normally suppressed and only summary
    information is displayed. This option will show even more test output.
```

- [Documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/ctest.1.html)